# Using Branch Office Printing with CUPS Server

Tags: networking, server, printing

we are thinking about the Implementation of a CUPS Server. There has to be a possibility for the employees to print if there is no connection to the print server. This could eventually happen if the WAN connection between the branches fails. We have to know what exactly happens if the server is not reachalbe. Unfortunately i have no good Ubuntu skills. It would be nice if someone knows the answer and would help me. Microsoft regulates this problem with the function Branch Office Direkt Printing.

Geetings Marie

PS: Sorry if my english is not the best, i am from germany

Comment: Would it work to have one print server per branch?

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer. No it is required that there is only one CUPS server at the main location. The branches should connect to the server over a vpn connection.

Comment: As far as I understand CUPS, the clients do not even know which printers are available if the server is gone. So I do not see how that would be possible to implement. Maybe somebody else has an idea, but I think you need at least one cups server per branch.